# How to deploy a apache Camel code in TomCat.?

Tags: apache-camel

How to deploy a Apache camel code to tomcat.? Do I need to convert the code to jar or War.? What it the procedure need to follow.?

Comment: This question is really broad and generic. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need make it as a WAR file. Refer [Official Documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/servlet-tomcat-example.html)